# Silverlight - Launch in explorer without toolbar

Tags: silverlight-2.0

Can anyone tell me how to take a silverlight app so that when I click on the link it starts the browser at a given size without toolbars. My java script skills are limited at the best of times, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are asking about opening a new window containing the silverlight app, write your link like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('SilverlightUrl', 'windowName', 'resizable,toolbar=no,location=no,scrollbars=no,width=480,height=320,left=0,top=0');return false;">Silverlight link</a>
```

This is a nice article about creating popup windows using javascript:
http://www.accessify.com/features/tutorials/the-perfect-popup/